# Is there a way to change the type of an input in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, semantic-ui-react, use-state

So I've tried the following, I can't seem to change the type of an input. So the same input can either be of type text or password but I can't switch between both. This is a Semantic UI Input. (from semantic-ui-react)

```
   const [inputType, setInputType] = useState('password'||'text')
```

in my JSX:

```
   <Input type={inputType} value={inputValue} onChange={handleInput} className="landingInput" placeholder={inputPlaceholder} />
```

at initialization:

```
  setInputType('text');
```

after an event:

```
  setInputType('password'); // should update html template with type="password" but it doesn't
```

useEffect is used to make sure state is updated, every other hook works as expected. Could this be a security precaution? Can you think of a way to avoid creating a new input?

Thank you

Comment: `should update html template with type="password"` ... Which template? It seems like much relevant code is missing from this question.

Comment: I mean the generated html template, I've updated the question with the relevant JSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggling input type is easy, 
Here I used a button to toggle the input type to `text` and `password`.
check the working demo [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jtyhqu).

Check the updated code block

```
const App=()=>{
  const [inputType, setInputType] = useState('text');
  const inputPlaceholder = 'Add Here';
  const handleInput =()=>{}

  const toggleInput = ()=>{
setInputType(inputType === 'password' ? 'text': 'password')
  }
    return (
      <div>
        <input type={inputType} value="password" onChange={handleInput} className="landingInput" placeholder={inputPlaceholder} />
        <button onClick={toggleInput} >Toggle type</button>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: setInputType(inputType === 'password' ? 'text': 'password') did the trick. thank you very much

Comment: @van do you  need the semantic UI fiddle ??. I can do that also